# Problems with a script in Angular and typescript using A-Frame

Tags: angular, typescript, aframe

I have a problem in angular with a script for a piece of HTML code that uses A-Frame to make 3D objects and interact with it. The problem is that you can give play with sound as an attribute of a-frame but when the script is tried or from the typescript it does not work and everything has been tried. I hope they can help me

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('play', {
  init: function () {
    console.log("entro al script play");
    var variable = document.querySelector('#yellow');
    this.variable.addEventListener('click' , function(){
      variable.components.sound.playSound();
    });
  }
});
AFRAME.registerComponent('stop', {
  init: function () {
    console.log("entro al script stop");
    var variable = document.querySelector('#yellow');
    this.variable.addEventListener('click' , function(){
      variable.components.sound.stopSound();
    });
  }
});
```

```
<a-box id="yellow" color="yellow" position="0 0 -5" sound="src:#bichota">
  <!-- Play -->
  <a-sphere color="green" radius="0.25" position="-1 1 0" play></a-sphere>
  <!-- Stop -->
  <a-sphere color="red" radius="0.25" position="1 1 0" stop></a-sphere>
</a-box>
```

In typescript I get this error "Property 'components' does not exist on type 'Element'"

```
var entity= document.querySelector('#yellow') ;
if(entity != null){
  console.log("enity" , entity);
  entity.components.sound.playSound();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use aframe in Angular, it is better to follow the angular practice instead of involving DOM operations directly.

For full demonstration, you can clone [my demo project on Github.](https://github.com/michael-vascue/test-ng-aframe)

**app.component.html**

```html
<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <audio id="bichota" src="../assets/test.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    </a-assets>

    <a-box id="yellow" color="yellow" position="0 0 -5" sound="src:#bichota" #yellowBox>
      <a-sphere cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" color="green" radius="0.25" position="-1 1 0" (click)="playSound()"></a-sphere>
      <a-sphere cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" color="red" radius="0.25" position="1 1 0"  (click)="stopSound()"></a-sphere>
    </a-box>
</a-scene>
```

- `#yellowBox` - for angular to reference it later on in the component logic
- `cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"` - for enabling element clicking by mouse. there is a need to specify cursor in the a-frame element. For details, you can read [the doc](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/cursor.html).
- `(click)="xxxx()"` - for binding click event

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  // refer to #yellowBox in the html
  @ViewChild('yellowBox') yellowBox!: ElementRef;
  
  playSound() {
    console.log("play")
    this.yellowBox.nativeElement.components.sound.playSound();
  }

  stopSound() {
    console.log("stop")
    this.yellowBox.nativeElement.components.sound.stopSound();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me, it really helped me too much and to better understand angular. It works very well thank you very much.